# CORDA: Invoke custom query on all parties involved in transaction

Tags: java, sql, database, corda

I have multiple questions on Corda:

1. Can we predefine the `h2` configuration to pick in `build.gradle` file?
2. I have a transaction in my `corda` network where i want to validate something based on `custom fields` the validation has to happen based on query that needs to be fired on all 3 parties `sender`, `receiver`, `notary` how can i fetch the session of all 3 nodes? i am able to pull the session of `sender` using `getServiceHub().jdbcSession()`
3. What will be the most suggested way to query a notary for custom fields? Can it be done using creating a sub-flow if yes then how?
4. we have validating and non validating notaries, where do we actually validate using notary? Where do we write the validation code?
5. how can we enable autosuggest in intellij for java api of corda?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can set the `h2Port` option in `deployNodes`:

   ```
   node {
       name "O=PartyA,L=London,C=GB"
       advertisedServices = []
       p2pPort 10005
       rpcPort 10006
       webPort 10007
       h2Port 10008
       cordapps = ["net.corda:corda-finance:$corda_release_version"]
       rpcUsers = [[ user: "user1", "password": "test", "permissions": []]]
   }
   ```

   Is that the kind of configuration you needed?
2. Each node's database is private by design, and cannot be queried from another node. Instead, you need to communicate with the other nodes as part of your flow in a way that causes them to initiate a response flow on their end where they query their own databases and send the results back. Something like:

   ```
   public class CollectDBDataFlow {
   @InitiatingFlow
   @StartableByRPC
   public static class Initiator extends FlowLogic<List<Object>> {
       Party counterparty;

       public Initiator(Party counterparty) {
           this.counterparty = counterparty;
       }

       @Suspendable
       @Override public List<Object> call() {
           // TODO: Implement queryMyDatabase to perform querying.
           Object myDBData = queryMyDatabase();

           FlowSession counterpartySession = initiateFlow(counterparty);
           Object theirDBData = counterpartySession.receive(Object.class);

           return ImmutableList.of(myDBData, theirDBData);
       }
   }

   @InitiatedBy(Initiator.class)
   public static class Responder extends FlowLogic<Void> {
       private FlowSession counterpartySession;

       public Responder(FlowSession counterpartySession) {
           this.counterpartySession = counterpartySession;
       }

       @Suspendable
       @Override
       public Void call() {
           // TODO: Implement queryMyDatabase to perform querying.
           Object myDBData = queryMyDatabase();

           counterpartySession.send(myDBData);

           return null;
       }
   }
   }
   ```
3. The role of the notary isn't to be queried for data, but to prevent double-spends. You could technically do it using the method described in (2) above, but it wouldn't be advised. What are you trying to achieve?
4. The validation logic is written into the platform. See https://github.com/corda/corda/blob/release-V1/node/src/main/kotlin/net/corda/node/services/transactions/ValidatingNotaryFlow.kt.
5. The auto-complete should appear automatically, just like any other library.

Comment: Can we define database's username and password too??

Comment: added one more question in main question

Comment: Thanks, answered. I don't believe you can define your database's username and password via `deployNodes` - you have to define it in your node's `node.conf` file.

Comment: Auto complete doesnt works for sample projects in java. it works fine for kotlin